# Snakemake workflow error: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, snakemake

I want to create a reproducible workflow using [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html), which is built on top of Python.

The `SAMPLES` is a list of strings in the `"./input/SRR_Acc_List.txt"` file and it matches to a substring of the `fastq` filenames.

An answer [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/how-to-resolve-in-snakemake-error-target-rules-may-not-contain-wildcards) suggested that a master rule `rule all:` should be used. But it raised an error.

First,

```
with open("./input/SRR_Acc_List.txt") as f:
    SAMPLES = ' '.join([line.rstrip() for line in f])


rule all:
        input:
                expand(html="qc/pretrim_fastqc/{sample}*.html", sample=SAMPLES.split(' ')),
                expand(zip="qc/pretrim_fastqc/{sample}*_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLES.split(' ')),
                "plots/quals.svg"

# Step 1: Pre-trim Quality Check
rule pretrim_fastqc:
        input:
                "./input/{sample}*.fastq"
        output:
                html="qc/pretrim_fastqc/{sample}*.html",
                zip="qc/pretrim_fastqc/{sample}*_fastqc.zip"
        params: "--quiet"
        log:
                "logs/pretrim_fastqc/{sample}.log"
        threads: 1
        wrapper:
                "v1.25.0/bio/fastqc"
```

Traceback:

```
tuple index out of range
```

SAMPLES:

```
SRR9200813
SRR9200814
SRR9200815
```

Fastq files:

SRR9200813_1.fastq
SRR9200813_2.fastq
SRR9200814_1.fastq
SRR9200814_2.fastq
SRR9200815_1.fastq
SRR9200815_2.fastq

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the our code again, I think the error is likely from *
If you want to do from list of string then

```
with open("./input/SRR_Acc_List.txt") as f:
    SAMPLES = ' '.join([line.rstrip() for line in f])

rule all:
    input:
        expand("fastq/{sample}_{fr}.html", sample = SAMPLES.split(' '), fr = ["1","2"])

rule fastq_files:
    output:
        touch("input/{sample}_{fr}.fastq")

rule fastqc:
    input:
        "input/{sample}_{fr}.fastq"
    output:
        "fastq/{sample}_{fr}.html"
    shell:
        """
        echo {input} > {output}
        """
```

A different version could be like this

```
with open("./input/SRR_Acc_List.txt","r") as file:

    SAMPLES = file.read().splitlines()

print (SAMPLES)


rule all:
    input:
        expand("input/{sample}_{fr}.fastq", sample = SAMPLES, fr = ["1","2"])

rule fastq_files:
    output:
        touch("input/{sample}_{fr}.fastq")
```